# Sprite Kit enumerating nodes to remove fails

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to enumerate nodes using their name, check their y position and if the value is lower than some number, run certain function on them. The nodes I am enumerating are part of other node, called blocks node. I set up my game this way because it is more convenient to apply action on the whole blocks parent node instead of on every block. This is my code for enumerating :

```
func chechForPassing(){
    var passedBlocks: [SKSpriteNode] = []
    enumerateChildNodesWithName("1") { node, _ in
        let node = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if (node.position.y <= self.frame.size.height*0.3) {
            passedBlocks.append(node)
            println("1")
        }
        for node in passedBlocks {
            self.fadeEnRemove(node)
        }

    }
```

where fadeEnRemove is just a function I wrote. Print is used for debuging purposes. This is how I set up my blocks:

```
    func block(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {

    var block = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "obsticle")
    kratkowski.size = CGSizeMake(block.frame.size.width*scaleFactor, block.frame.size.height*scaleFactor)
    block.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
    block.name = "1"
    blocksNode!.addChild(block)

}
```

And block node is SKNode. Anyone knows how to solve this little problem?

Thanks!

Comment: there isnt enough info here to debug.  what does "fadeEnRemove" do?  also, I dont understand why youd nest a loop with passedBlocks inside your enumeration.  it seems like it should be on the outside

Comment: the problem is not fade function since I dont get print in my console. I use this list because there is a possibility that more than one block will fall into this category under the same update.

Comment: fade function is just a function which takes sprite as an argument and runs remove action (SKAction.removeFromParent)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, the enumeration block is never being called. This is probably because either the child nodes names aren't "1", or you aren't calling enumerateChildNodesWithName on the correct node.

Right now you're calling enumerateChildNodesWithName on self. Are these nodes added to self or are they added to another node? If they're on another node then call enumerateChildNodesWithName on that node instead.